# Can dom-repeat child elements be bound to array items?

Tags: javascript, dom, polymer, focus, dom-repeat

I am trying to create a simple note list using Polymer 2 where each note is shown in an `<input>` element. To create the list of `<input>` elements, the `<dom-repeat>` component is used. I noticed that when an item from the array is removed, all the `value`s of the `<input>` elements are shifted upwards and the last `<input>` element is removed. Is there any way to instead delete the `<input>` element that was associated with the deleted array item?

I realize that typically, this would not be a serious issue, but with the `<input>` element, the focus is bound to the actual DOM objects. To get the focus right, the `value` attributes of the `<input>` elements shouldn't change when a note is deleted.

Below is my code for my notes list component and the note-atom component.

```
<dom-module id="note-list">
<template>
    <ul>
    <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{notes}}">
        <li>
        <note-atom
            on-delete="_onNoteDelete"
            on-blur="_onNoteBlur"
            value="{{item.note}}">
        </note-atom>
        </li>
    </template>
    <li>
        <note-atom value={{_newNote}}></note-atom>
    </li>
    </ul>
</template>

<script>
    class NoteList extends Polymer.Element {
    static get is() { return 'note-list'; }
    static get properties() {
        return {
        notes: {
            type: Array,
            value: [],
            notify: true
        },
        _newNote: {
            type: String,
            value: '',
            observer: "_newNoteChanged"
        }
        };
    }

    _newNoteChanged(newValue, oldValue) {
        if (newValue !== '') {
        this._newNote = '';
        this.push('notes', {"note": newValue});
        }
    }

    _onNoteDelete(e) {
        const noteIdx = this.notes.indexOf(e.model.item);
        this.splice('notes', noteIdx, 1);
    }

    _onNoteBlur(e) {
        if (e.model.item.note === '') {
        this._onNoteDelete(e);
        }
    }

    }

    window.customElements.define(NoteList.is, NoteList);
</script>
</dom-module>


<dom-module id="note-atom">
<template>
    <input type='text'
    value="{{value::change}}"
    on-blur="_onInputBlur"
    placeholder='A new note...' />
    <button on-click="_onDeleteButton">X</button>
</template>

<script>
    class NoteAtom extends Polymer.Element {
    static get is() { return 'note-atom'; }
    static get properties() {
        return {
        value: {
            type: String,
            value: '',
            notify: true
        }
        };
    }

    _onDeleteButton() {
        this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('delete'));
    }

    _onInputBlur() {
        this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('blur'));
    }
    }

    window.customElements.define(NoteAtom.is, NoteAtom);
</script>
</dom-module>
```

Comment: why you need to remove an item from the array

Comment: I would like the user to be able to delete a note.

Answer (score 0):

I found that this type of behaviour is implemented in dom-repeat but hasn't been merged into the master branch yet. More details can be found here: https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/issues/4558